# Restart node.js script with bash script every 2 hours

Tags: node.js, bash, shell

hi guys I want to restart my Nodejs script every 2 hours with bash script but i dont know how it can wor like this

```
node app.js
```

its will start the app.js but its start at once - I want to start script every 2hours

Comment: Do you happen to have ever heard of cron?

Comment: whats is the  cron?

Comment: `cron` is a UNIX mechanism to start scheduled taks. You can read more about it online (for instance, [here](https://ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/))